# How to set a default value using getter and setter

Tags: jsp

Hi I am trying to set a default value 00 for a field in domain file that contains getters and setters.

When no data is inserted, it should have a value of 00.

```
private String tapeStartHour;

public String getTapeStartHour() {
return tapeStartHour;
}

public void setTapeStartHour(String tapeStartHour) {
this.tapeStartHour = tapeStartHour;
}
```

But I dont know where I should put

```
set value='00'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value on the declaration:

```
    private String tapeStartHour = "00";
```

Or, on your getter:

```
    public String getTapeStartHour() {
        return tapeStartHour.equals("") ? "00" : tapeStartHour;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using:

```
private String tapeStartHour ="00";

public String getTapeStartHour() {
return tapeStartHour;
}

public void setTapeStartHour(String tapeStartHour) {
this.tapeStartHour = tapeStartHour;
}
```

P.S. You cannot use `''` notation. It is used for `char`. For `String` you have to use `""` notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
private String tapeStartHour;

public String getTapeStartHour() {
 if(tapeStartHour == null)
     setDefault(); 

return tapeStartHour;
}

public void setTapeStartHour(String tapeStartHour) {
      if(tapeStartHour == null)
           setDefault();
this.tapeStartHour = tapeStartHour;
}

private void setDefault() {
  tapeStartHour = '00';
}
```